# Как найти максимально значение масива?

Tags: c#

Кто подскажет как найти и вывести в отдельной строке максимальное значение массива?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Текущая дата и время " + System.DateTime.Now);
        int[] A = new int[15];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            A[i] = rand.Next(-100, 300);
            Console.Write(A[i] + "  ");
            
           
        }

       
        string p = Console.ReadLine();
       
    }
}
```

Comment: Просто `A.Max()`?

Comment: @VladD, это только если System.Linq подключен

Comment: Ммм.. А без неё ?)

Comment: @Grundy: Да, а также если версия .NET Framework ⩾ 3.5

Comment: @KOKO: Если это реальный код, то используйте `.Max()` и не морочьте нам голову. Если это учебное задание, то го вручную, цикл и сравнение с текущим наилучшим элементом.